# Как в autoinrement-ный столбец записывать подряд только уникальные значения?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, структуры, структуры-данных

В базе данных проекта (php, mysqli) есть таблица, в которой один из столбцов объявлен уникальным:

```
Indexes 
PRIMARY id auto inkrement
UNIQUE  auth_id
```

Логика приложения: регулярно по cron мы получаем список auth_id и простым запросом

```
INSERT INTO
```

мы отправляем в базу данных все auth_id, и соответственно в базу записываются только уникальные значения. Так и надо ( но возможно в плане архитектуры приложений неправильно и/или избыточно).

Предварительной проверки на наличии auth_id нет, и в масштабах именно основной роли - не требуется.

**Проблема:**

Сейчас в столбце id следующие значения:
1,2, 6,12,13,15....
Предполагаю, что пропущенные id принадлежат попыткам записать не уникальное значение.

**Вопрос:** как заставить базу данных считать автоинкрементный id только для уникальных значений?

Comment: *как заставить базу данных считать автоинкрементный id только для уникальных значений?* Как - не вопрос, ибо никак. Вопрос - зачем это может понадобиться. Автоинкрементный синтетический ключ - это поле, в которое пользователю совать нос вообще противнопоказано, а программисту - только чтобы убедиться, что до переполнения значения ещё очень далеко. Нужна непрерывная нумерация? заведите ещё одно поле, и в нём нумеруйте.

Comment: @Akina "никак" - не есть путь решения данного вопроса.

Comment: Некорректный вопрос не предполагает корректного ответа. Управлять значениями, которые присваиваются в автоинкрементное поле, в принципе нельзя (кроме задания начального значения - и то, сработает лишь при отсутствии бОльших значений). Всё. Это by design и не обсуждается. А альтернативное решение дано - *заведите ещё одно поле, и в нём нумеруйте*.